# jquery slideUp don't work?

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

In this code my menu slides down correctly, but then I click button my menu slides up without animation.. Any thoughts what's wrong?

```
      if($(this).hasClass('menu-opened')){
        $('#cssmenu').css({backgroundColor: '#333333'});
  $("#menu-button").css("font-size", "12px");
  $('#cssmenu ul:first').slideDown();


      } else {
         $('#cssmenu').css({backgroundColor: ''});
   $("#menu-button").css("font-size", "0px");
   $('#cssmenu ul:first').slideDown();
      }
```

Comment: include a fiddle so that the problem can be worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Both are set to "slideDown()". It's probably disappearing only because you set the font-size to 0.

```
   if($(this).hasClass('menu-opened'))
       $('#cssmenu ul:first').slideUp();
   else 
       $('#cssmenu ul:first').slideDown();
```

I wouldn't manipulate any other things in this unless necessary. Remember that you must have transformation set in CSS if you want to animate changing font-size/color.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I noticed that but still, slides down, but don't slide up, font-size 0 and 12 is important, and even without it doesnt make any change.

Comment: What library are you using? JQuery UI?

Comment: Forgot that SlideUp/Down was part of JQuery core. :) I don't think a solution is possible from just this. There must be some CSS conflicting with it. If you could make a JSFiddle that replicates it and post that here, I could look closer at it.